# Need to return json obj so I display in list view getting back nil

Tags: ios, json, swift, callback, return

I am very new to swift. I am trying to return back the JSON and view it in a list view, I cant get the JSON from my AppApi class to return back to my viewDidLoad(). Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.
Teli

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let api = AppAPI(token:self.toPassToken)
    var test  = api.getOrders()

    println("why does test come back as an empty array")
    println(test)
    println(test.count)
}


class AppAPI {
    var token: String
    let apiEndPoint = "endpoint"
    let apiUrl:String!
    let consumerKey:String!
    let consumerSecret:String!
    var returnData = [:]

    init(token:String){
        self.apiUrl = “hidden-for-security”
            self.consumerKey = "token"
        self.consumerSecret = "my consumer secret"
        self.token = token
    }

    func getOrders() -> [JSON] {
        return makeCall("contacts")
    }

    func makeCall(section:String) -> [JSON] {

        let params = ["token":"\(self.token)"]

        Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(self.apiUrl)", parameters: params)

            .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) -> Void in
                println("error \(request)")
                self.returnData = json! as! NSDictionary




        }

        return results!
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this code would compile, it includes `return results!` which is never defined.

Answer (score 0):

In your  `makeCall(section:String) -> [JSON]` function you are returning `results!`.  Where is `results` ever set in this function?

Did you mean to return `returnData` instead?

Answer (score 0):

`Alamofire.request` performs an asynchronous request; `responseJSON` will execute that closure when the request completes at some point in the future.

You almost certainly do not want to block your `viewDidLoad` method until this request finishes as that would block your main thread and leave the app unresponsive. Instead start the request in `viewDidLoad` and react whenever the request finishes.
One way you might do this is by passing a closure to `getOrders` which you could execute when the request finishes.

Comment: Can you provide and example? I am looking up closures now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The important point is that you decouple starting the request from receiving the response and realize you can't just wait for the response. How you implement this really depends on what you want your app to do, a simple version might be for your `viewDidLoad` to provide an async callback block (`api.getOrders { orders in /*...*/}). Your question doesn't describe how you plan to use that JSON response once you have it.